# Pass a string instead of type in JsonUtility.FromJson<>()

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, methods, types

So I've been learning how to make asynchronous multiplayer games, cool stuff.

To make my code look better I wanted to be able to pass a class name as a string, this would make my code a lot better to read because I could use this function for my requests:

```
public IEnumerator DoWebRequest(string url, string jsonData, string classToPass)
{
    WWWForm _form = new WWWForm();
    _form.AddField("json", jsonData);
    using (UnityWebRequest _webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, _form))
    {
        yield return _webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        var _response = JsonUtility.FromJson<StringHerePls> (_webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        //Debug.Log("LocationX: " + _response.locationX + " LocationY: " + _response.locationY + " LocationZ: " + _response.locationZ);
    }
}
```

I've tried using:

- System.Type.GetType(classToPass)
- System.Type.GetType(classToPass).MakeGenericType(classToPass);
- Variations of the above include making it a local variable and using that variable.

The error I get when using the mentioned System.Type.GetType(classToPass):

- Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'Type'

To try out if this conversion worked at all I tried using:

```
var _response = JsonUtility.FromJson< System.Type.GetType(classToPass) > (_webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
```

to get a reference to a script,
this **did** work.

So I'm at a loss for how to get this to work, I just don't get why the GetComponent did work but the FromJason did not.

Comment: can you avoid " pass a class name as a string" just pass to a class or struct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JsonUtility.FromJson(string, Type)` overload and use reflection to find a Type with name matching `classToPass`.

Something like this:

```
Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.IsDynamic).SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes()).First(t => t.Name == classToPass);

var response = JsonUtility.FromJson(_webRequest.downloadHandler.text, type);
```

Comment: I've gotten your code to work by using:



`using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

//Added these "using" lines to be able to use Appdomain and .Where()

Type _type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.IsDynamic).SelectMany(a => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()).First(t => t.Name == classToPass);
var _response = JsonUtility.FromJson(_webRequest.downloadHandler.text, _type);
`

Problem: I used to be able to access the returned variables by doing:
Debug.Log(_response.locationX);



But this no longer works.